# call an ASP.net (not MVC) webmethod and get a json response, so I can then iterate through a list with foreach (of d3.js)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, d3.js

Trying to call a webmethod and use the json returned so I can swap from the .csv file in the example here:

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/area-gradient.html

I can get json returned by using jQuery but the code inside the callback "data.foreach" does not work, so it's not formatted the way d3 needs it. How do I do this with the json library from an asp.net page to an asmx webservice **using D3** (not jQuery) so the data.foreach below works? using D3 I am just getting null back when I try to serialise a list of objects and return as Json. Note - returning one item is OK (I can create and call a webmethod to return a guid). But in order to get the D3 example to work I need to get the json back in the format the example expects...thanks. BTW I can do this with MVC, I need it for ASP.net though...

```
d3.csv("flights-departed.csv", function(data) {

// Parse dates and numbers.
data.forEach(function(d) {
d.date = parse(d.date);
d.value = +d.value;
});

// Compute the maximum price.
x.domain([new Date(1999, 0, 1), new Date(2003, 0, 0)]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

// Bind the data to our path elements.
svg.select("path.area").data([data]);
svg.select("path.line").data([data]);

draw();
});
```

UPDATE

I've been trying to fix this all day.

I updated the d3 library to allow calls to webmethods, as per the following article:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/d3-js/-u_P9BF1COs/VP9Q1vaSJgAJ

Now I can call and get a JSON encoded object back no problem. When Itry and do the same and have a list of objects returned, it always comes back from the webmathod as a null.

To explain...

This works:

```
function loadAnOBJECTViaJSonVIA_ASP_FRAMEWORK() {

    var sUrl = "http://localhost:3791/DemoServices.asmx/GetSingleObject_VIA_ASP_FRAMEWORK";

    alert('d3.json - ' + sUrl);

    d3.jsonasmx(sUrl, function (data) {

        var d = data.d;

        alert('I got the following OBJECT back:' + d);
        alert('reading property: ' + d.ppGuid);
        alert('reading property: ' + d.x_value);
        alert('reading property: ' + d.y_value);
    });
}
```

calling:

```
[WebMethod]
        public PointPair GetSingleObject_VIA_ASP_FRAMEWORK()
        {
            PointPair pp = new PointPair();

            return pp;
        }
```

This doesn't work:

```
function loadOBJECT_Array_ViaJSonVIA_ASP_FRAMEWORK() {

            var sUrl = "http://localhost:3791/DemoServices.asmx/GetObjectArray_VIA_ASP_FRAMEWORK";

            alert('d3.json - ' + sUrl);

            d3.jsonasmx(sUrl, function (data) {

                var d = data.d;

                //alert('I got the following TOP LEVEL OBJECT back:' + d);

                //alert('reading property: ' + d.ppGuid);
                //alert('reading property: ' + d.x_value);
                //alert('reading property: ' + d.y_value);
            });
        }
```

calling:

```
[WebMethod]
        public PointPairList GetObjectArray_VIA_ASP_FRAMEWORK()
        {
            string testResultsID = "26881";
            List<PointPair> pointpairs = this.GetTestResultPointsPaired(testResultsID);

            PointPairList ppl = new PointPairList();

            ppl.ListOfPoints = pointpairs;

            return ppl;
        }
```

Really stuck...in the second example inside the callback function data is null. I've tried wrapping the of points in the .ListOfPoints property as yu can see, but that didn't help.

Comment: Can you post what your data looks like when it is received from you ASP/ WebMethod?  That would make it easier to figure out what you need to change to get it d3-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

If the data you're getting is in JSON format, use [`d3.json()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json) instead of `d3.csv()` to parse the data.

The rest of the code should then work **if** your JSON is formatted as an array of objects.  If it's formatted as one large object with named entries, you'll also need to look at [`d3.entries()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_values) to convert to an array.

Comment: That didn't really help, thanks anywway. I've been trying to suss this out all day. I'm part of the way there...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but try making sure you set the `ResponseFormat` to `ResponseFormat.Json` in your web method. JSON is a standard, so what works in jQuery should work in any other library. Chances are that the JSON is invalid.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
    public PointPairList GetObjectArray_VIA_ASP_FRAMEWORK()
    {
        string testResultsID = "26881";
        List<PointPair> pointpairs = this.GetTestResultPointsPaired(testResultsID);

        PointPairList ppl = new PointPairList();

        ppl.ListOfPoints = pointpairs;

        return ppl;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. No dice. It's so strange...and I can't believe nobody has posted about this before